# Why does using sleep(1) is not the same thing as 1 - (time() - initTime

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I am studying a code and i want to understand why using this:**

initTime = time()
sleep(1 - (time() - initTime))

**instead of:**

sleep(1)

The purpose is just to count down the time out until 30, so...

Is not the same thing?

```
from time import time, sleep    

def __wait_for_element__(self, element_tag, locator, timeout=30):
        """Wait till element present. Max 30 seconds"""
        result = False
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(0)
        locator = locator.upper()
        for i in range(timeout):
            initTime = time()
            try:
                if locator == 'ID' and self.is_element_present(By.ID, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                elif locator == 'NAME' and self.is_element_present(By.NAME, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                elif locator == 'XPATH' and self.is_element_present(By.XPATH, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                elif locator == 'CSS' and self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTORS, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                else:
                    logging.info(f"Error: Incorrect locator = {locator}")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(e)
                print(f"Exception when __wait_for_element__ : {e}")

            sleep(1 - (time() - initTime))
        else:
            print(
                f"Timed out. Element not found with {locator} : {element_tag}")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT)
        return result
```

Comment: It would only be the same thing if `time() - initTime` was zero. Does that help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: @kaya3 Omer Sherer explained my question very well, i was wondering about the difference of using sleep(1 - (time() - initTime)) instead of only sleep(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time() - initTime` is the time of reading each repetition of the loop.

For a single repetition of the loop, it takes **time() - initTime** for reading + **1 - (time() - initTime)** of sleep.

**At total**: 1 - (time() - initTime) + (time() - initTime) = **1 second**.

Therefore, when using `sleep(1 - (time() - initTime))`, each loop repetition time is very close to 1 second.

Why not using `sleep(1)`? -Because it is not as precised. Each loop iteration will last for more than 1 second: (time() - initTime) of reading it + 1 second of sleep.

Comment: *"exactly 1 second!"* not exactly, because `sleep` is not perfectly accurate itself, and neither is `time()`. But it should be more accurate this way than just doing `sleep(1)`.